# Why am I getting graphical error while booting?

Tags: boot, drivers

I have successfully installed Ubuntu and it runs perfectly. But, why is there only a pink and purple screen while it boots?

My machine specs are 2nd Gen i3 2.4ghz, 8gb RAM, Intel HD graphics and AMD Radeon HD switchable.

Comment: These are two questions. Ask them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I also see the "pink and purple" screen when booting because of speed related checks. I am assuming this is normal since the PC boots too fast for the plymouth logo (The cool Ubuntu logo with the animation) to appear, it simply defaults to a basic screen (The pink and purple one).

(The above needs verification from additional users since I have only tested this with my computers and some friends. Faster computers or booting faster means skipping the animated logo).

On my fast computers (Core 2 Duo 8500 and an i7 2600) this always happens. For a slower (still fast) one a Pentium 4 2.4Ghz, I can see the loading screen fine (The ubuntu logo).

BTW, Updates are done automatically, you will get a Update Manager window saying "Hey buddy, you got some new updates ready". If you do not want to wait simply go to a terminal and:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: oh thank you sir it works about updates, but in my booting problem i will ignore it .  important is successful boot

Comment: Glad to help, do not worry about the pink and purple, it just means you have a fast computer although a nice quick logo of Ubuntu would be nice to see right ^^.